# Textbox positioned with 'Absolute' is moving out of place on window resize

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a textbox that I created outside my main form with the below code:

```
 <div class = "Box">
  <form action="javascript:someThing()">
   <input type="text" id="RandomID" />
  </form>
  </div>
```

I then tried using the following CSS to position said textbox:

```
  div.Box
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 50%;
 right: 20%;
}
```

I felt quite certain that this was the CSS needed to absolutely position my textbox. However, upon resizing or zooming of my window the textbox moves to far and won't stay in place with the rest of the page elements. What have I done wrong with my CSS?

Comment: what do you think `bottom:50%;right:20%;` do?

Comment: Positions the div based on percentages as opposed to using 'px', allowing the div to maintain its place within the page upon resizing.

Comment: ok, so what is your question? why div which is supposed to move during resize actually moves during resize?

Comment: No, just why it doesn't move with the rest of the page like it should.  It instead moves way to far and is out of place.

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: What is the div positioned relative to? Do you have another positioned element that it's a descendent of?

Comment: No, this element is sitting outside my main form all by its lonesome, I'm sure that has something to do with it but I don't know what.